# How to display data on Rails form for nested attributes - Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid3

I've got a model like this:

```
class User

    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

    ...
    field :import_settings,     :type => Hash,          default: lambda { default_values }

    def default_values
        {
            hosts:      '',
            port:       '',
            database:   '',
            user:       '',
            password:   ''
        }
    end

end
```

And my form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, {:url => admin_path, :controller => 'stactic_pages', :action => 'update_import'}) do |f| %>

      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      ...

      <%= f.fields_for :import_settings do |p| %>

          <%= p.label :hosts %>
          <%= p.text_field :hosts %>

          <%= p.label :port %>
          <%= p.text_field :port, placeholder: :port %>

      <% end %>

      <%= f.submit 'Save changes', class: 'btn btn-large btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

All works fine and I can collect/save/update the data, however on the front end the data in the hash (that has been previously saved) is not being displayed. Any ideas why?

Btw, on my controller I do have the following:

```
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attribute(:import_settings, params[:user][:import_settings])
        flash[:success] = 'Details saved'
        redirect_to admin_path
    else
        flash[:error] = 'An error happened'
    end
```

This is a custom controller to update only part of the user details. (Not the main edit page for users).

Answer (score 0):

Update your code from

`<%= f.fields_for :import_settings do |p| %>`

to

```
<%= f.fields_for @user.import_settings do |p| %>
```